# Query data.table dinamically for all columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to generalize this code for all possible columns in a`data.table`:

```
dat_fun[col_1080 != '' & !is.na(col_1080), .(col_1080 = .N)]
```

A simple case of this is when I just want to count unique values for all columns, and return a single row with each unique value for each column:

```
  expr2 <- parse(text = paste0(".(",
                               paste0(paste0(allCols, " = uniqueN(", allCols, ")"), collapse = ", "),
                               ")"))
```

This generates the following expression:

```
.(col_1067 = uniqueN(col_1067), col_1068 = uniqueN(col_1068), ...)
```

And then, this code `tmp2 <- dat_fun[ , eval(expr2)]` generates the desired output, a `data.table` with one row:

```
col_1067 col_1068 col_1069 col_1070 col_1071 col_1072 col_1073 col_1074 col_1075  ...
1:      991        5        3      122      114      106       71     1001      576  ...
```

But I am not being able to generate a similar expression using `paste` and `parse` to operate both on `i` and `j` in the `data.table`. What I have tried is, for a single column:

```
expr=parse(text="col_1080 != \'\' & !is.na(col_1080), .(col_1080 = .N)")
```

But this results in this error:

```
Error in parse(text = "col_1080 != '' & !is.na(col_1080), .(col_1080 = .N)") : 
  <text>:1:34: unexpected ','
1: col_1080 != '' & !is.na(col_1080),
```

Besides, I would need to generalize to work for all columns, like the first example. Problem is, I do not know if it is possible, since the first approach works only on one section of `data.table` (`j` in this case). It is possible to write an expression that works both on `i` and `j`?

### Update

Thanks to @Roland comment I am almost there, but it seems to be failing for dates:

```
dat_fun[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x != "" & !is.na(x))][, lapply(.SD, sum)]
# Throws 
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

### Update 2

This worked!

```
dat_fun[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.character(x) != "" & !is.na(x))][, lapply(.SD, sum)]
```

Comment: Like this? `DT <- data.table(a = c(1:5, ""), b = c(NA, "", 1:4)); DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) uniqueN(x[x != "" & !is.na(x)]))]`

Comment: @Roland Oh!, that seems to be the solution, didn't know unique took params. One thing, I am getting `charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format` Would I need to cast all to string?

Comment: @Roland but your solution generates as many rows as `DT` has, could it be  possible to only compute it once? like in my first example?

Comment: @Roland Can you post your comment as an answer?